# React: How do I render an array in the data table extension, once state is updated?

Tags: reactjs

**On successful response, the `state` is updated but am failing to render it to the react data table extension.** There is no data shown in the table but there is actually a column inserted in the `table` [react-data-table-component-extensions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component-extensions). My goal here is to list all the users to the table. I'll share some code snippets:

[image: Invisible Data]

**State:**

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    user_list:[]
  }
}
```

**Mount:**

```js
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('/api/list_users',{
    // ...    
  }).then(res => {
    this.setState({ user_list:res.data.user });
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

**Render method:**

```js
 <DataTableExtensions
   columns={columns}
   data={this.state.user_list}
 >
    <DataTable
        noHeader
        defaultSortField="id"
        defaultSortAsc={false}
        pagination
        highlightOnHover
    />
 </DataTableExtensions>
```

Comment: Try `console.log`ging your `res.data.user` and see if it contains the correct array.

Comment: hi, i got this on my console. 1: {fullname: "test test", address: "sadsadsada", email: "dfgfd@gmail.com", contact_number: "asdasdasdasd"}

Answer (score 0):

This works with Hooks like this:

Firstly you need an useState hook to update your objet data.

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

After this we create the petition with axios or fetch an set the data response:

```
useEffect(()=>{
 axios.get('/api/list_users',{
    // ...    
  }).then(res => {
    setData(response.data)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
},[]);
```

And finally we add the view

```
<DataTableExtensions
   columns={columns}
   data={data}>
   <DataTable
      pagination
      paginationComponentOptions={paginationOptions}
      fixedHeader
      highlightOnHover
    />
</DataTableExtensions>
```